# Detecting Unrecognized (codepage-unicode) Characters in a string

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding, character, detect

How do you detect an unrecognized code page character in a string in vb.Net? These charaters usually show up in a default character such as "?" or a square when the current code page can not recognize the original character from some other output.

I have text fields from an external source that displays the "square" character for some long dash character (not chr(150)) and I want to be able to replace it with character code 45 (dash) to make it compatible but I can't determine how to check for the default special "unrecognized" character in a replace. I searched the net but can't find a solution to this problem! I played with System.Text.Encoding but still can get what I want. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see this question was asked quite a while ago, I figure you found the answer by now. At any rate, this is what I'm doing at the moment. I look for the specific characters I want to replace and in another array I put what I want them to be changed to. I hope this works for you.

```
Private Function CleanText(TextToClean As String) As String
    Dim CleanedText As String = TextToClean
    Dim BadText(5) As Char
    Dim GoodText(5) As String

    BadText(0) = ChrW(169)  ' © (alt 0169, copyright)
    BadText(1) = ChrW(174)  ' ® (alt 0174, registered trademark)
    BadText(2) = ChrW(8482) ' ™ (alt 0153, trademark)
    BadText(3) = ChrW(8364) ' € (alt 0128, Euro)
    BadText(4) = ChrW(176)  ' ° (alt 0176, degrees)

    GoodText(0) = "(c)"
    GoodText(1) = "(r)"
    GoodText(2) = "(tm)"
    GoodText(3) = "(euro)"
    GoodText(4) = "o"

    For i As Integer = 0 To BadText.GetUpperBound(0)
        CleanedText = CleanedText.Replace(BadText(i), GoodText(i))
    Next

    Return CleanedText
End Function
```